# Профайлер под Linux

Tags: профилирование, c, c++, linux

Не подскажите хороший профайлер C/С++ кода под Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)

Comment: valgrind не позволяет отслеживать время выполнения и количество вызовов различных функций. На сколько я помню, valgrind позволяет лишь отследить утечки памяти.

Comment: Ссылка указывает на callgrind (он считает кол-во вызовов).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/).

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо профилировать довольно низкоуровневый код, то, возможно, с этим справится лучше всего [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

IDE Netbeans содержит в себе встроенный профилировщик